# consider using one to other

Tags: prepositions, meaning-in-context

Me and my tutor at work came across this sentence which I understood slightly different in our language than him:

> Where possible, consider alternative diuretic therapy (e.g., thiazides) to more potent diuretics (e.g., furosemide) in elderly patients receiving risperidone.

So, which diuretic should now be used? I think the former (thiazide), but my tutor doubts and asks a question whether the sentence could be formed alternatively without a loss of meaning. Like these schematic examples:

- Change A to B
- Change A for B
- Prefer A to B
- Consider A against B

In my opinion only "prefer" (A to B) and "consider A against B" could stay in place of "consider alternative" (A to B). But I am in doubt now, too. Suddenly it has become a hard nut to crack.

I would be very pleased if someone could give us a hint at least.

Comment: That is a very odd sentence to begin with. I would understand it as being a strange, botched-up form of “Consider using A instead of B” (= preferring A over B), but ‘consider A to B’ is not idiomatic to me. (‘Consider A against B’, by the way, does not make sense—I can’t even guess which way the preference is supposed to go in that one.)

Comment: I definitely read it as: Consider A as a [preferred] alternative *to* B.

Comment: Yes. Substitute *prefer* for consider and it works just fine. Or *consider (thiazides) as an alternative to (furosemide).*

Comment: I think it's two constructions fused: i) _consider A instead of B_ and ii) _consider an alternative to B_. I think the writer was misled by the word _alternative_ to think it was ii), though it had started as i).

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your helpful comments and suggestions. I didn't dare hoping I would be responded to in such a prompt manner. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

The author is trying to avoid telling you that furosemide is contraindicated for elderly patients who are taking risperidone.  It is not, but you should "consider" using a weaker diuretic first.  The construction that you quote is idiomatic medicalese; the author is strongly hinting that you should consider multiple factors, err on the safe side, but then not leave the more aggressive approach completely out of your consideration.  The writer is trying to organize your thinking (your consideration, if you will) without dictating a therapy.  In other words, if something goes wrong, it is the reader's fault, not the writer's.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Sartin for your answer. Owing to your in depth explanation our patient will be treated safely ;)